# mongoose model to connect to mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

i have created model for the mongo collection like below. but it was giving me the collection output which saved in mongoDB.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    age: {
        type: Number
    },
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('container', Schema);}
```

But later when i changed the last line of the code which is

> "module.exports = mongoose.model('container', Schema);"

to

> "module.exports = mongoose.model('container', Schema, 'container');"

it worked properly. I check the mongoose document they say to use the previous line, then why didn't it worked.

Answer (score 0):

your problem seems to be from using "Schema" as a variable name

```
var ContainerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ...
});
```

and exporting

```
module.exports = mongoose.model("Container", ContainerSchema);
```

would work.

Comment: `var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var ContainerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    contId: {
        type: String
    },
    missions: {
        type: Array
    },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("container", ContainerSchema);` ** tried this solution, but didn't work**

Comment: what do you mean by it didn't work ? when you tried importing (requiring) it from another file, you didn't get the model ?

Comment: I didnt get the model in subsequent file, so query can be performed on model.